# Using group by and order by in Doctrine

Tags: doctrine

I have one database table called ms_message: with 6 columns (id, senderid, receiverid, content, isRead, receivedTime). I want to get the latest received message group by sender in Doctrine but I cannot run the sub query or use order by and group by as well.

The query in SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ms_message WHERE receiverId = :receiver ORDER BY receivedTime) GROUP BY senderId;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Doctrine supports queries like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...)`

Comment: Although it supports raw SQL queries.